# How to Click on a button using css selector

Tags: java, html, webdriver

Can any one help me how I can click on button HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span16">
<div class="pull-right">
<a class="btn primary" href="/v2/admin/user/edit" style="background-color: rgb(54, 67, 149);">Create</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to click on Create button using web driver JAVA

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-a-button-in-webdriver-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

If you are using selenium, you can use css seletor as jQuery do.
Try:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("btn:contains('Create')")).click();
```

Comment: not working it shows following error Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An invalid or illegal string was specified
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:45'

 at Shingo.main(Shingo.java:148)
Caused by: