# Button click selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="onOpenSessionClick()" value="Open device access">
```

But when I do the command:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Open access device' and @type='submit']")).click();
```

The click does not.
Here is my code:

```
if (isElementPresent((By.xpath("//input[@value='Open device access']")))) 
{
    System.out.println("Je suis dans le if");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Open device access' and @type='submit']")).click();
    System.out.println("Je suis dans le if et jai open");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div/div/p/span")));                       
    assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/input")));                     
    assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/input[2]")));                      
    System.out.println("Je suis dans le if et je cherche");
}
```

Comment: I am also having the same problem, any solution? For my case ,the browser  is fired up,does A..B..C then when it reaches the point to click that button, the browser closes up.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this one too as CSS Selector

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][value='Open device access']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button']")).click();
```

Comment: thank you My problem is not with the click but finally that the button is in a javascript accordion. But the element is not visible so I think the javascript is not executed. A solution?

Comment: Can u look into this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-a-button-in-webdriver-using-javascript).I think may be this will resolve u r problem.But no fully sure on this.

Comment: Thanks but I think of my webdriver seveur does not execute the javascript. Locally all my script works.
My server is on a Debian 1.6.0 and Iceweasel

Answer (score 3):

`type` in your case is `button`, not `submit`.

Try this one `//input[@value='Open device access']` or
`//input[@value='Open device access' and @type='button']`

Comment: Thank you
My problem is not with the click but finally that the button is in a javascript accordion.
But the element is not visible so I think the javascript is not executed.
A solution?

Comment: I do not understand a question totally, could you please provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether this button is on frame or not. If it is, then you need to switch to the frame and then locate and click.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Good Note Helpful to others

Answer (score -2):

Just try the below code for `click`

```
selenium.focus("name=Valuation"); //name of button
selenium.click("Valuation"); //pass that name to click
```

Comment: OP is using Webdriver bindings not the original Selenium.