# Selenium - Clicking a flash button

Tags: javascript, java, flash, selenium

I'm loading a URL using Selenium in Mozilla, which basically contains a 'Login' button made in flash, which I want to click.
I went through the following resources:
1.[How to click an element in Selenium WebDriver using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-a-button-in-selenium-webdriver-using-javascript), but the solution didn't work for me.

2.https://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/, but it doesn't tell me how to click on a button.

Here is the element code:

```
<embed width="100%" height="105%" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"; allowscriptaccess="always" name="TTDSWeb" bgcolor="#ffffff" quality="high" id="TTDSWeb" src="TTDSWeb_V15.6.3.swf" allowfullscreen="true" allownetworking="all">
```

Using "FlashFireBug", I'm able to get the id of the 'Login' button, but I'm unable to click on it.[image: Login button and it's id using FlashFireBug]

Comment: can you provide the test-code you got so far? and the url of the site where you are trying to click the button

Comment: @drkthng The URL is: http://ttdhwc001.global.ad.sabre.com:8080/TTDSWeb/TTDSWeb.html. On the page, I aim to click the "Login" button whose object id is "loginbut".
Though I doubt whether you would be able to access this URL, as this is my organization's web page.

Comment: unfortunately url is not accessible, not in the www is it? it's on your companies intranet or sth? So maybe you post some lines of the html you see around the button, then I can suggest sth you could try

Comment: haha, sorry didn't read the whole comment of yours. Second part of my comment still holds.

Comment: @drkthng Sorry for late reply. Here's the html:<embed width="100%" height="105%" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" allowscriptaccess="always" name="TTDSWeb" bgcolor="#ffffff" quality="high" id="TTDSWeb" src="TTDSWeb_V15.6.3.swf" allowfullscreen="true" allownetworking="all">

Comment: if you already tried the way in my answer, please provide the code for how you currently try to click the button. cheers

Comment: updated my answer -> have a look at this 
https://seleniumonlinetrainingexpert.wordpress.com/2012/12/02/how-to-do-flash-testing-using-selenium-webdriver/

Answer (score 0):

Hi please note selenium is only for HTML objects it does not works for Flash Object as they have Difference structure to add support of Flash You need a Third party tool integration like Sikuli please have a look at this answer [Selenium Integration with Sikuli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252116/flex-monkium-integration-with-selenium-ide/33255327?noredirect=1#comment54335553_33255327)

This will show you how you can work with flash objects in selenium