# flex monkium integration with selenium ide

Tags: apache-flex, testing, automation, selenium-ide

I am newbie for flex automation , is there any possible way to integrate flex monkium wtih selenium ide to record particular test cases as we can do for any web application in selenium ide

Comment: no there is no such way however you can do flash automation in selenium web driver by using Sikuli in java language if you need tutorial i can share that with you

Comment: sure ! thats more appreciated

Comment: @fahad one more question is it feasible to use this in long term, for example is this maintainable if new changes occur

Comment: yes it is feasible to use it in long run because its image based automation

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if its use full to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Sikuli for automation of flash Please check this link for Flash automation Tutorial to start with basic [Turtorial](http://testingtoolstecniques.blogspot.com/2015/04/using-sikuli-api-with-selenium-web.html)

Sikuli API for Java provides image-based GUI automation functionalities to Java programmers. It is created and will be actively maintained bySikuli Lab. The effort of making this API is a response to the desire of many Sikuli users to use Sikuli Script's functionalities directly in their Java programs, rather than writing Jython scripts. This new Java library has a re-designed API and includes several new functions that were not available in the original Sikuli Script, such as the abilities to match colors, handle events, and find geometric patterns such as rectangular buttons. 
You can also download this eclipse project from :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B09BIsDTY_AuYVB4ZjJNM3h0ZlE/view?usp=sharing

Steps:

1. Open Eclipse IDE
       Create a new Project
       Download Selenium Bindings 
       Download Sukuli JAR
       Right click on you project
       Open New>Class

   ```
   Right click on you project





   Open Build Path>Configure Build Path


   Open Libraries Tab

   Click add External Jars button
   Add Following Imports 

   import java.io.File; import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


   import org.junit.After; import org.junit.BeforeClass; import
   org.junit.Test; import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; import
   org.sikuli.api.*; import org.sikuli.api.robot.Mouse; import
   org.sikuli.api.robot.desktop.DesktopMouse;


       Add Selenium and Java Bindings 
       Paste Following code in Your Class

   @BeforeClass
   public static void setUp() throws Exception {
       wd = new FirefoxDriver();
       wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   ```

   }

   ```
   @Test
   public void TestCase1() throws InterruptedException {

   }

   @After
   public void tearDown() {
       wd.quit();
   }

   public static boolean isAlertPresent(FirefoxDriver wd) {
       try {
           wd.switchTo().alert();
           return true;
       } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
           return false;
       }
   ```

   }
2. Open Flash Calculator Link in Browser
   “http://www.terrence.com/flash/calculator.html “
3. Take small images of required number and operations like 1.png,2.png
   , equal.png and multiply.png etc. you can use snipping tool utility
   for this purpose its pre-installed in Win 7 or greater

   Like These
4. Now Create  function which takes path of image as string and click
   on that image

Code is:

```
public void click_Image(String img)
{
  s = new DesktopScreenRegion();
 target = new ImageTarget(new File(img));
  r = s.find(target);


 // Create a mouse object
  mouse = new DesktopMouse();
 // Use the mouse object to click on the center of the target region
 mouse.click(r.getCenter()); 
}

Now add Following code in your test case first navigate to URL by web driver and then click by images which you created example code is 



 @Test
    public void register() throws InterruptedException {
     wd.get("http://www.terrence.com/flash/calculator.html");
     click_Image("IMG\\1.png");
     click_Image("IMG\\0.png");
     click_Image("IMG\\plus.png");
     click_Image("IMG\\2.png");
     click_Image("IMG\\equal.png");
    }
```

Your final code would be:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.sikuli.api.*;
import org.sikuli.api.robot.Mouse;
import org.sikuli.api.robot.desktop.DesktopMouse;


public class testAutomation {
public static FirefoxDriver wd;


ScreenRegion s;
Target target ;
ScreenRegion r; 


// Create a mouse object
Mouse mouse ;


public void click_Image(String img)
{
  s = new DesktopScreenRegion();
 target = new ImageTarget(new File(img));
  r = s.find(target);


 // Create a mouse object
  mouse = new DesktopMouse();
 // Use the mouse object to click on the center of the target region
 mouse.click(r.getCenter()); 
}
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        wd = new FirefoxDriver();
        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void register() throws InterruptedException {
     wd.get("http://www.terrence.com/flash/calculator.html");
     click_Image("IMG\\1.png");
     click_Image("IMG\\0.png");
     click_Image("IMG\\plus.png");
     click_Image("IMG\\2.png");
     click_Image("IMG\\equal.png");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        wd.quit();
    }

    public static boolean isAlertPresent(FirefoxDriver wd) {
        try {
            wd.switchTo().alert();
            return true;
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: i found this very interesting, i just wanted to confirm lets suppose in near future i wanted to do this for chrome and if some how resolution is affected, still this would be able to cater those images ? your help is really appreciated Thanks

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on Stackoverflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: sikuli works on what is shown at screen it damms care rather its chrome IE or some other broswer i tried it even on desktop apps it worked for me