# Selenium button click does not work

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am working on `cloudbase` project which is having user authentication module. User can be authenticated to system using user credentials and also with using `OAuth` authentication.

I am automating this with Selenium but when I am trying to click on 'sign-in' button it does not work,

```
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() 
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("Application URL");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }

    @Test
    public void enterCredentials() 
    {
        driver.findElement(By.id("cred_userid_inputtext")).sendKeys("email address");
        driver.findElement(By.id("cred_password_inputtext")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("cred_sign_in_button")).click();
}
```

I have tried same using `sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)` and with `sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)`

Also tried using Actions

```
{
WebElement signIn_button = driver.findElement(By.id("cred_sign_in_button"))

Actions enterSignIn = new Actions(driver);
enterSignIn.moveToElement(signIn_button);
enterSignIn.click();
enterSignIn.perform();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to locate element? It is possible that multiple elements can be available  according to your xpath.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: I have tried it with using XPath and also with other locators.

Comment: Not getting any error, Only issue is, 'click' does not work. It locate 'Sign-in' button and shift focus on it,but doesn't land up user on main page.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, on some pages Firefox seems to require special treatment for Click(). I solved it this way (in C#, but Java should be similar):

```
// special workaround for the FirefoxDriver
var actions = new Actions(driver);

actions.MoveToElement(element);

ToolBox.DisableTimeout(testParams);
actions.Release().Build().TryPerform();
ToolBox.EnableTimeout(testParams);

actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Click().Build().Perform();
```

Explanation: I explicitly call Release() before calling Click(). Sometimes it's necessary, sometimes it isn't. If it is *not* necessary, then calling Release() ends up in waiting until the implicit timeout (if you have any) is over and then raising an exception. That is why I temporarily disable the timeout when calling Release() and also why I wrap it in a TryPerform() method, in order to ignore the exception. A look inside my TryPerform() method:

```
public static bool TryPerform(this IAction action)
{
    try
    {
        action.Perform();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I know, there are no extension methods in Java, but you can probably solve this similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Some times sleep before click will simulate click correctly. like

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("cred_sign_in_button")).click();
```

If above one does not works, as you already tried with all locators and Actions, so try with java script executor

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("cred_sign_in_button"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("cred_sign_in_button"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
[enter link description here][1]executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Visit  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can try explicit wait with [expected conditions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("cred_sign_in_button"))).click();
```