# Execute javascript in Selenium with Facebook PHP WebDriver

Tags: php, facebook, selenium, facebook-php-webdriver

I am trying to follow [this documentation](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/Example-command-reference#synchronous-script-execution) to execute a script, and all I am getting is an error saying the `executeScript` method is undefined.

```
$this->driver->navigateTo('/');
$this->driver->clickElement('#member_opt_in + label');
$this->driver->executeScript("alert('Hi');");
```

The documentation uses `$session`, and says higher up the page that this is shorthand, but doesn't explain anywhere at all what `$session` actually contains or how to assign it.

Comment: which browser are you using? could be something failing on browser side

Answer (score 4):

The [wiki](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki) on GitHub is not up-to-date with the current php-webdriver library and refers to previous (pre 2013) version of it - but the library was rewritten from scratch since.

To execute Selenium commands you need instance of `RemoteWebDriver`. An example can be seen in [readme](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver#getting-started).

With `RemoteWebDriver` instance in `$driver` variable you can execute:

```
$driver->get('http://google.com');

$element = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('#member_opt_in + label'));
$elemen->click();

// Execute javascript:
$driver->executeScript('alert("Hi");');
// Or to execute the javascript as non-blocking, ie. asynchronously:
$driver->executeAsyncScript('alert("Hi");');
```

Refer to [API documentation](https://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/) for more information.

Comment: which version is needed?

Comment: @AndrewVakhniuk Well any 1.0.0+, but why don't you try ty latest one - 1.6.0.

Comment: Excellent explanation Ondrej and I followed some of your comments on github as well, do you think we can use the executeAsyncScript to figure out if Ajax stopped loading? I'm trying to figure this out via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64590437/php-webdriver-wait-for-ajax-to-finish-executing

Answer (score 1):

For people using Laravel Dusk (and in my case I wanted to click a Facebook modal to test a federated login via Socialite):

```
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;

$confirmationButton = $browser->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('.layerConfirm')); 
$browser->driver->executeScript("arguments[0].click();", [$confirmationButton]);
```

This seemed to force the click even though previously screenshots from Dusk were showing that a dark (mostly black) translucent layer was hovering over the whole screen, preventing any clicks (even though in normal non-Dusk attempts, everything in the browser looked fine).

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11956130/470749
- https://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/1.3.0/Facebook/WebDriver/JavaScriptExecutor.html

P.S. I also later realized that the Facebook modal had a fancy gradual transition when it was inflating / appearing, so it seems that `$browser->waitFor('.layerConfirm', 4)` was firing prematurely, so I thought I could instead just use `pause(2000)` to force it to wait a full 2 seconds for the transition to complete (and then wouldn't need to use `executeScript` at all). But no amount of pause let the modal become fully visible and clickable.