# How to test calendar events with Vaadin Testbench

Tags: vaadin7

I have a view with a `Calendar`. To this component I have added some events which can be clicked and trigger some code by handlig the `EventClick` event with `EventClickHandler()`.

I am trying to test those events from Vaadin via Vaadin Testbench (4.0.3). Using `TestBenchTestCase`'s method findElement()  as follows :

```
public WebElement getCalendarElement(){
    return  findElement(By.className("v-calendar-event"));
}
```

I retrieve the event element correctly, but when `.click()` method over the element is invoked, there's not EventClick arising.

I also tried using as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-javascript) :

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", getCalendarElement());
```

for the click function and neither id it work.
How can I get Testbench to click the element?

Comment: Tested it with Vaadin 7.7.3 & TB 4.0.3 and it works as expected. Can you provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org) which reproduces this problem?