# Can't inspect an element

Tags: html, selenium, testing

i am trying to inspect an element . When i right click and inspect that element i see the below things

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oClrP.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYJQp.png)

I tried below but it didn't worked for me

```
driver.findElement(By.id("tmsMobileId")).click();
```

Can someone please help me here.

Comment: What do you mean didn't work?? Is there any exception or something else??

Comment: Check if there any frame in your webpage. If yes, please switch to the frame first and then try. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the web page is not loading completely when the click() executes, so it won't be able to find what it is supposed to click on.  You may need to sleep the script for a couple seconds.

Otherwise, take a look at this link:

[How to click an element in Selenium WebDriver using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-javascript)