# Selecting a row in ext-js grid using selenium webdriver does not work for IE

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I have a scenario where i need to select a row in grid in ext-js application using selenium webdriver. Based on row selection some buttons enabled.
The html snippet is as below

```
<div id="ext-element-55" class="x-grid-item-container" style="width: 756px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);" role="presentation">
    <table id="tableview-1812-record-288" class="x-grid-item x-grid-item-selected" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style=";width:0" data-recordindex="0" data-recordid="288" data-boundview="tableview-1812" role="presentation">
        <tbody>
            <tr class=" x-grid-row" role="row" aria-selected="true">
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1825 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1825" tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" style="width: 378px;">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:1;" unselectable="on">FirstElementToSelect</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1826 x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1826" tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" style="width: 378px;">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:1;" unselectable="on">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="tableview-1812-record-289" class="x-grid-item x-grid-item-alt" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style=";width:0" data-recordindex="1" data-recordid="289" data-boundview="tableview-1812" role="presentation">
        <tbody>
            <tr class=" x-grid-row" role="row" aria-selected="true">
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1825 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1825" tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" style="width: 378px;">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:1;" unselectable="on">SecondElementToSelect</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1826 x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1826" tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" style="width: 378px;">
                    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:1;" unselectable="on">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

WebElement Click (tried on div/tr/td/table - all elements) works fine for Chrome and FF and selects the row but it does not select row for IE. Also tried action classes, robot APIs but these also do not work on IE.
Is there a way to make it work in IE using native events (apart from using javascript to select). Note that on using requiredWindowFocus it does work in IE but i do not want to use this as it has limitations
of parallel work on same machine and running tests on remote locked machines.

Selenium version - 2.53.0
Browser - IE11
IE driver version 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems this click issue continues since IE 9. [Check here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4403).

However, please try these methods. It might be a workaround for now.

- Change `driver capabilities`. 
  `DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
  capabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents",false);
  capabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
  WebDriver driver = new  InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);`
- Try `javascript click`. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-javascript).
- Try `keys.ENTER`. [Official docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html).
  `driver.findElement("path")).sendKeys(KEYS.ENTER);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, i used javascript as workaround as do not want to use synthetic events.

Comment: Great. Please select the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please share more details like IE version, Selenium version.

Please note there already some issues reported for Click event in IE 9, 10 and also in 11. Find more [here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4403).

Comment: HI, Added the selenium and browser version - checked the link shared though i understand there are issues in IE related to click not sure if any of these fixed. Though one such issue suggested to use requireBrowserFocus but i want to avoid using same (because of limitation of this for remote and parallel execution).