# Elements are not identified properly, whats wrong?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

in my Angular application i am identifying an element with its id. But its not recognizing during the execution and below are my details.

In my screen, i have a Loan number control with loan value and its checkbox as checked state. I have to find out whether after the screen launch, this loan number is checked or not. I have scripted with its identified (id) but during the execution it not recognized and it throws 'Element not visible' error. Any help please..

[image]

```
<section class="verification-element" data-ng-show="$ctrl.value || $ctrl.vmodel=='isIvrVerified'" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="verification-element--nameValue" data-ng-switch="$ctrl.type">
        <label for="loanNumberid" class="verification-element__name ng-binding">LOAN NUMBER</label>

        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: address -->
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: percentage -->
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: select -->
        <!-- ngSwitchDefault: --><span class="verification-element__value ng-binding ng-scope" id="loanNumberValueId" data-ng-switch-default="">0553101437</span><!-- end ngSwitchWhen: -->

    </div>
    <div class="verification-element--checkbox saturn-checkbox">
        <input class="checkBoxFirstPanel ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" type="checkbox" name="loanNumber" id="loanNumberid" data-ng-checked="true" data-ng-model="$ctrl.thing" data-ng-click="$ctrl.checkedElement({name: $ctrl.vmodel, value: $ctrl.thing})" checked="checked" aria-invalid="false" style="">
        <label for="loanNumberid"></label>
    </div>
</section>
```

When i checked with my developer, he says that he has put 'id' for this checkbox control as "loanNumberid" i also scripted with that. but when i inspect it actually shows the `<lable>` control and i am confused on this. here is my selenium code

```
@FindBy(id = "loanNumberid") 
public static WebElement chkloan;

chkloan.click();
```

and i get the error as...

```
 org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
        (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.76)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
      Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds
      Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10 09:43:55'
      System info: host: 'MUS5CG6030CWS', ip: '10.219.18.222', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
      Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
      Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed), userDataDir=C:\Users\par964\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir17000_14241}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=56.0.2924.76, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
      Session ID: a8514260e4e55f5ff09b60d0196223f4
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:50)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.click(Unknown Source)
        at com.capitalone.Pages.NewVerificationModal.clickCheckBoxes(NewVerificationModal.java:360)
        at com.capitalone.Steps.Saturn_Login.selectElements(Saturn_Login.java:490)
        at ?.And I select fields on verification panel(src/test/resources/feature/SmokeCICD/NotesMemo.feature:12)
```

Comment: test with xpath

Comment: Thanks. But i am not sure why its is pointing to label control though it has angular input field with id specified.

Comment: I am not sure about it but there is no closing tag for input checkbox, so I think you need to have enclosing tag like this  `<input class="checkBoxFirstPanel ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" type="checkbox" name="loanNumber" id="loanNumberid" data-ng-checked="true" data-ng-model="$ctrl.thing" data-ng-click="$ctrl.checkedElement({name: $ctrl.vmodel, value: $ctrl.thing})" checked="checked" aria-invalid="false" style="" />`

Comment: You might try waiting for the element to be visible. There may be a delay before it actually becomes visible. You could also try a CSS selector, `input[name='loanNumber']`.

Comment: Tried by css selector also. still its not recognizing..any other suggestion please..This actually blocks our testing...

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure that there are no elements with same ID in the DOM model
2. Make sure that element is not overlapped with smthn else
3. Try clicking either [JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-javascript), either using [Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html)

Comment: If it were overlapped, it would give a different error... another element would receive the click. Using JSE is not a user scenario because no user will use JSE to make the element visible or to click it. Actions won't click an invisible element either.

Comment: @Mikhail - for some reason my expected checkbox element is not visible in the page during the script execution and script always says that error message 'element not visible...'. But i used this js `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", chkloan);` executor and it works perfectly and the checbox is clicked and dono how. Anyways thanks for the hint.