# What are "lsdata" and "lsevents" attributes

Tags: html, selenium, webautomation

I am new to selenium. Trying to Automate form filling using selenium. I need to click a button with following  tag.

```
<a class="urLink urT" id="mq120h" ct="LN" lsdata="{0:'Move\x20Left',1:'Back',4:true,7:'ESCAPE'}" lsevents="{Activate:[{ResponseData:'delta',ClientAction:'submit'},{}]}" tabindex="0" ti="0" title="Move Left (Escape)" href="javascript:void(0);" ondragstart="var e=window.event;e.cancelBubble=true;e.returnValue=false;return false;" style="white-space:nowrap;"><img border="0" align="absmiddle" src="/sap/return.gif" alt="Move Left" ondrag="return false">&nbsp;Return</a>
```

I am unable to understand what are these attributes "lsdata" and "lsevents" in the above .../ tag doing. Whether they are creating any dynamic link? How I can execute the same thing using script executor functions in Selenium.

I don't want to click using the FindElement() method as the element (button) is deeply nested in a table. 
Thanks

Comment: You can click a button by using javascript `driver.execute_script('your script here')` but please post whole source code because maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: My understanding is this tag is calling some function to create link. How can I do it through selenium?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to click an element in Selenium WebDriver using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-javascript)

Comment: I suspect this is a SAP interface and the element does not respond to selenium clicks. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
     jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('link name or Id').click();");
```