# Not able to perform the actions on dropdown because calendar pop up after sending expiration date by sendKeys

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my code I wrote this code to enter the expiration date by SendKeys

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#passport-exp-date-input-243202807"))
      .sendKeys("2021-05-13");
```

now after entering the date, the calendar pops up with this date and due to this, I am not able to perform the next action which is selecting gender which is a dropdown.

the code for thar is below:

```
String locator = "select[id='passport-gender-243202807']" + 
      "[data-sync-to-element='#citizenship-info-view-passport_gender-243202807']"
Select dropdownGender = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector()));

dropdownGender.selectByVisibleText("Female");
```

It is  giving me an error:  “Element is not visible”

**Html for expiration date:**

```
 <input required="" type="text" id="passport-exp-date-input-243202807"
        name="documentExpirationDateInput" 
        class="form-control expirationDate input-sm orange-calendar 
               sync validDateFormat date-picker-selector hasDatepicker"
        data-language="en" data-date-format="yy-mm-dd" 
        data-end-date-of-trip="2018-07-07T00:00:00.000-04:00" 
        data-min-date="0" data-max-date="" 
        data-sync-to-element="#citizenship-info-view-document_expiration-243202807" 
        data-ocr="" value="">
```

**Html for gender:**

```
<select required="" type="text" name="gender" id="passport-gender-243202807"
        class="form-control input-sm sync" data-ocr=""
        data-sync-to-element="#citizenship-info-view-passport_gender-243202807">
    <option value="">Gender</option>
    <option value="M">Male</option>
    <option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
```

**Screenshot of Gender**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// input expiration date
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#passport-exp-date-input-243202807"))
      .sendKeys("2021-05-13");

// click any element on page which is not covered by the calendar pop-up
// to make the calendar close, so that it won't cover the Gender element
driver.findElement(<any element no covered by calendar>).click()

// if it's native dropdown,
// click on the dropdown to expand all options
// Generally, for native dropdown, no need to expand options
// we can directly click the option without expand all options.
driver.findElement(By.id("passport-gender-243202807")).click()

// click the wanted option
driver.findElement(By.id("passport-gender-243202807"))
      .findElement(By.xpath("./option[text()='Female']")).click()
```

Comment: I am able to get away from thr calendar but is doesn't do the next action

Comment: The `get way` means the calendar pop-up be closed?

Comment: Yes the pop is now closed after clicking other element on the page but now it's selecting gender it failed there as female test is not visible

Comment: Please give the heading 20 lines and the ending 20 lines HTML code around the Gender dropdown,  I suspect it's not a native dropwdown, but a CSS dropdown, like http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

Comment: I updated code, you can try and to see it will fail at line `driver.findElement(By.id("passport-gender-243202807")).click()` and report `element not visible`.  If reported, means it's not a native dropdown.   (Native dropdown implement purely by HTML `select` and 'option' tag)

Comment: Yes it is a css dropdown please see the code in question above

Comment: But the give HTML code of the Gender is only includes `select` and `option` tags.  This means it's a native dropdown. If it's not. Please give more  HTML code, 30 lines above the `<select>` and 30 lines behind `</select>`

Comment: Sir  it is working fine with your updated code thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I am pretty sure it should work:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("passport-gender-243202807")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Female");
```

Or if selecting by text doesn't work, try selecting by index:

```
dropdown.selectByIndex(2);
```

Also, to automatically trigger a click event on some other visible element to make the popup calendar go away, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11956130/8065825

**UPDATE:**

I have just noticed an error in your dropdown HTML: you're placing the `</select>` closing tag before the dropdown options so clearly that won't work. Try this instead:

```
<select required="" type="text" name="gender" id="passport-gender-243202807" class="form-control input-sm sync" data-sync-to-element="#citizenship-info-view-passport_gender-243202807" data-ocr="">
    <option value="">Gender</option>
    <option value="M">Male</option>
    <option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried this nd still the same error element female is not visible

Comment: please see yong answer it worked fine thanks for the help and suggestions