# How to for loop though html element uisng python selenium to click each element in a page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to like and unlike all the post present in an Instagram feed page. I'm able to like a first single post not able to find a way to like multiple posts . I'm using XPath to get an element of that page

```
comment_like_xpath="//button/span[@class='glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7' and @aria-label='Like']"
comment_unlike_xpath="//button/span[@class='glyphsSpriteHeart__filled__24__red_5 u-__7' and @aria-label='Unlike']"
```

I can click on single first post using this xpath as below

```
comment_like_elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,comment_like_xpath))).click()
```

if I use list of elements present in page I get exception error

```
comment_like_elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(comment_like_xpath)
comment_like_elem_len = len(comment_like_elem)#no  of liked elemets
```

If I iterate through list of elemensts I get an exception error

```
for element in  comment_like_elem:   
    element.click()
```

each elements are

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="53072af595e97e0c84dfadcabbe3b44e", element="97c695b9-1ae0-4a37-a0fd-5ff5a52a2b1f")>
```

I get an exception at element.click() as

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message:
>   element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (487, 743). Other
>   element would receive the click: ...   (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

element of the like button is as below

```
<button class="dCJp8 afkep _0mzm-"><span class="glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7" aria-label="Like"></span></button>
```

even I tried uisng this xpath

```
//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/article[1]/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button/span
```

and iterating through this it gives me a same ElementClickInterceptedException error after liking a single post

code i written  to login to page is as bellow

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1')

browser = webdriver.Chrome('path of chromedriver', options = options)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
try:
    browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
except TimeoutException:
    print('continue')
    browser.close()
    exit()
time.sleep(3)
login_elem_usr = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div/div/form/div[4]/div/label/input')
login_elem_usr.click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']"))).send_keys("username")
login_elem_pwd = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div/div/form/div[5]/div/label/input')
login_elem_pwd.click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']"))).send_keys("password")
login_elem_login = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div/div/form/div[7]/button/div')
login_elem_login.click()
time.sleep(5)
try:
    login_elem_popup = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")))#.click()
    login_elem_popup.click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("contine")
try:
    filterButtonElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")))
    filterButtonElement.click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("contine")
```

So how can I like all the post present in my feed ? any suggestions will be helpful thanks

Comment: Can you post a picture of the website? From what I'm seeing in an Instagram Avengers feed, these buttons are not visible, unless I click the picture first

Comment: @RegCent I'm opening page through mobile version page. I have updated code have a look at the code

Comment: Seems that your element is behind some loading element, did you tried to wait for the overlapping element to be invisible, also did you tried to scroll to the element?

Comment: @SpencerMelo yes I tried both of them delaying and scrolling down the page I get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send click event by js. Maybe it helps you

```
comment_like_elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,comment_like_xpath)))
for item in comment_like_elem:
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", item)
```

Comment: thanks your solution works perfectly. It worked. can u explain me how u did that?

Comment: @deepinside, I think, this post can explain you how the js scripts works in selenium (and this case in particular ) . Gleed to help you.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-javascript)