# how can i selenium javascript code click?

Tags: python, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K2Th.png)

site : data.go.kr

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chromedriver = 'C:/Users/B0114/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

driver.get('http://www.data.go.kr/tcs/dss/selectDataSetList.do')

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="#tab_layer02"]')
elem.click()

lloyd = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href='javascript:void(0)']")

for ll in range(5):
    lloyd[ll].click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/double-click-and-right-click-selenium.html

Comment: possible duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javascript with selenium to click an element, you can do this:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', element)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your Click function is not working because of javascript:void(0).
You should try

```
 lloyd[ll].submit()
```