# org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a project that I am working on with java and selenium. My element click is intercepted due to infinite loader.
This is the issue I get:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <span class="select2-selection__placeholder">...</span> is not clickable at point (329, 179). Other element would receive the click: <div id="loader" style="display: block;">...</div>
```

How can I resolve this? My code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'select2-user-auto-complete-select-container\']/span")).click();
        WebElement m =driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/span/span/span[1]/input"));
        m.sendKeys("jimmy");
```

[image]

Comment: Click using JS should do the job, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-javascript

Comment: Check for a `select` tag below.