# What would be the cause of clicking failure in selenium for this checkbox?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a page as this,
[image]

And I want to click the top checkbox, which by default, would automatically select all the checkboxes in that list. As you can see, I have created the xpath value, and it matches the checkbox area that I want to pick. But when I was to have it executed in selenium, the checkbox checking never happens.

```
 xpath_var = "//th[@class='selection-cell-header']/div[1]/input[1]"
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_var,))).click()
```

And here is the exception I have received:

```
      selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input class="ftnt-checkbox" readonly="" type="checkbox" id="" value=""> is not clickable at point (305, 162). 
Other element would receive the click: <label for="ftnt-checkbox"></label>
```

Any idea what could be wrong ? work around for such case?  Manual clicking was ok, in that case.

Thanks,

Chun

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Hi Akzy, I have just updated with the exception message I got in my question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message indicates that there is another element that will receive the click. This is a kind of protection in Selenium.
You can try to click this label that is on top of your element. Or click the parent div. Or click your element with JavaScript.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfd"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Reference:
[How to click an element in Selenium WebDriver using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have just tried, and it does the trick.